# What are the synctex.gz files and what they need for?

Tags: auxiliary-files

I think the title is self explanatory but neither here ([Egad! What are all those files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53240/egad-what-are-all-those-files)) nor here ([File extensions of LaTeX-related files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-of-latex-related-files)) I found a detailed answer

Comment: Duplicate of [What exactly is SyncTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118489).  See also [Why does LaTeX gzip the synctex file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116560).

Comment: Above link is to OLD 1.16 (2008-2011) since 2011 its hosted at [GitHub](https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex) version1.22 can be found at http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/synctexdir/